# Internal Server Error and the htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

my website just work perfect and this is my **htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(google3ab2a69cd4d1.html|BingSiteAuth.xml|index.php|sitemap.xml|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and i just want to add new folder to my website after i add its and its called

> matrix

and then tried to access by browser and its show me forbidden of Course because of the htaccess file must add the folder name on htaccess so i add it and htaccess be like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(google3ab2a69cd4d1.html|BingSiteAuth.xml|matrix|index.php|sitemap.xml|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

and my webiste stop working its give me **Internal Server Error**

so i just back on step and removed the folder name from **htaccess** and same its show me **Internal Server Error**
i delete the htaccess file and the website work but some page need **htaccess** for work

so what the mistake here

Comment: You need to find out what the actual issue is. "Internal server error" is a "dummy" indicating an internal error, but since the actual issue is sensitive that is not published. Instead you need to take a look into your http server's error log file. That is where you can actually _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_ ...

Comment: @arkascha i slove it by change the file encode to `ANSI`